# How to construct MS-VECM model

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit the Markov Switching-Vector Error Correction Model (MS-VECM) using the package MSwM in R. Now, I have been working and I've got the results of VECM and MS regression already. However, I've got stuck in the process of MS-VECM. Could any one help me pls, and here is the code that I'm using:

#### Check Johansen MLE

```
myVECM <- lineVar(data, lag=1, include="const", model="VECM", estim="ML")
summary(myVECM, digits=4)

olslgdp <- lm(d.lgdp ~ d.lex+d.lim)
summary(olslgdp)
```

#### MS

```
mslgdp = msmFit(olslex, k = 2, sw = rep(TRUE, 3))
summary(mslgdp)
```

#### Diagnostics for Markov Switching

```
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
plotDiag(mslgdp, regime=1, which=1)
plotDiag(mslgdp, regime=1, which=2)
```

Comment: Especially for r program

Comment: Why is this tagged MATLAB if you're programming in R? That doesn't make sense. Please [edit] the question to contain the correct tags.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I corrected it already.

In fact, I'm using R program but I's also started to run with Matlab.